# Onclick Button is not being called React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I have this component that processes a card and when you click it redirects you to a past route but your OnClick is not working. I wonder if I could be going wrong

```
  function Characters({
  characters,
  getAllCharacters,
  filterCharacters,
}) {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    characters.length === 0 && getAllCharacters();
  }, [getAllCharacters]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Search characters={characters} />
     { inputCharacters !== "" && filterCharacters.length > 0 ? (
        <ListContainer>
          {filterCharacters.map((characters) => (
            <CardItem
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(`/characters/${characters.id}`, {
                  params: { characters },
                });
              }}
              key={characters.id}
              name={characters.name}
              images={
                characters.thumbnail.path + "." + characters.thumbnail.extension
              }
            />
          )}
        </ListContainer>
```

Component CardItem:

```
 export default function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <Container url={props.images}>
      <Content>
        <p>{props.name}</p>
      </Content>
    </Container>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: What is your `Container ` and `Content`?

Comment: Can you provide a lot more detail about what isn't working? Is there an error? What is the actual versus expected result? Where does `CardItem` use the `onClick` prop? It needs to be passed on to an interactable DOM element, like a `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using `onClick` in the `CardItem`. You just update like this:

```
<p onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</p>
```

If `Container` or `Content` support `onClick`, you cant put `onClick={props.onClick}` in this component like a prop